# Jupiter Quote API Error: quoteResponse Error: Query parameter inputMint cannot be parsed: WrongSize

Tags: solana-program, api, jupiter

My code:

```
const quoteResponse = await (
await fetch('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112\
&outputMint=EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v
&amount=100000000
&slippageBps=50'
)
).json();

console.log(quoteResponse);`
```

I'm getting the following error:
`{ error: 'Query parameter inputMint cannot be parsed: WrongSize' }`

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. In your code I see the URL has line break and spacing. Try removing those so that the entire URL is in one line as a single string without any spacing in between any characters.